# Question on formatting author

Tags: titles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Desktop/} }

\title{Improvement of the Cascadic Multigrid Algorithm with a Gauss Seidel Smoother to Efficiently Compute the Fiedler Vector of a Graph Laplacian}
\author{Shivam Gandhi \href{email: [email]}
\and \href{Tufts University Department of Mathematics}}
\date{November 2015}
```

I am writing a paper and the above code is causing problems when I compile in TeXworks through pdfTeX. It returns this issue:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\@author ->Shivam Gandhi \href 
                           {email: shivam.jgandhi@gmail.com} \and \href ...
l.20 \maketitle
```

I am not sure why this error is happening. I wrote the paper in ShareLaTeX and it compiled fine, but now there are problems.

Comment: `\href` is part of the `hyperref` package, and usually has the syntax `\href{URL}{text}`. If you try adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` and use that syntax, does it help?

Comment: I added that line and it caused a new error:                                       Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \usepackage
               [utf8]{inputenc}

Answer (score 4):

`\href` refers to a `h`yper `ref`erence that you want to include. In order to do so, you need to include

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

in your preamble. Note that there may be conflicts when using that package. If this occurs, [load order may be important](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764). Additionally, `\href[<options>]{<URL>}{<text>}` takes *two* mandatory arguments. The first would be a URL, while the second is what's displayed in the text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Here is a title}
\author{A Author \href{abc}{abc}
  \and B Author \href{def}{def}}

\date{November 2015}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Minor nit: The first argument of `\href` need not be URL. It could also be (especially in the case of an email address) something like `mailto:somebodys.userid@someplace.com`. Clicking on such a link won't load a website but, rather, invoke an email program and open a page with the recipient's address inserted in the "To" line.

Comment: @Mico: True. One can include any hyperlink directive, including `mailto:` or otherwise.

Comment: @Mico `mailto:somebodys.userid@someplace.com` is also an URL – just with a different scheme. Have  a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator for more information.

Comment: @Benjamin - Thanks for this. I didn't know that the term URL was so general.

Answer (score 1):

I would use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}%% only for demo
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Here is a title}
\author{A Author\thanks{\url{abc@de}}
    \and B Author\thanks{\url{def.de}}}
\date{November 2015}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is better, indeed.